# How to stop subsequent packets after returning NF_DROP with netfilter?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, packet-capture, packet-sniffers, netfilter

To block some URLs, with `netfilter`'s `NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT` chain, when I return `NF_DROP` for some packets, I am getting multiple packets for same request. I want to stop subsequent packets to avoid unwanted process of blocking same URL.

Is there any value like `NF_DROP`, that I can return to stop this process, so that requester - *i.e. web browser in my case* - display some error page instead of repeating request for same URL?

Can I replace requested URL in packet and then return `NF_ACCEPT` so that requester will get a page and stop requesting?

Answer (score 0):

The client (in your case - the browser) doesn't know why what he sent was not accepted by the server. The client expected to get an ack, and it didn't. So he continues resend the request.
You should send a reset packet to the client (with server's IP address) for stopping the requests.
For displaying an error page it's more complicated, but possible.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this by queueing packets from kernel space to user space throuch `netfilter`, and then sent error html page to clients after processing.

Comment: This is good, but you can steal the packet, rewrite the IP addresses and the ports, raise the RST flag, fix the checksum of both IP and TCP and return NF_ACCEPT.